# Report viewer in C#

Tags: c#, report

I have found some discrepancies while working with Reports in application development. Whatever the data updated in running form are not reflecting immediately in the report, have to close the form and again to debug to see the updates in report.

Please send your valuable suggestions to reflect data instantly in report once it gets updated.

Comment: Are you talking about dynamically updating the report while the data in the background is updating?

Answer (score 3):

why don't you simply click the refresh button? you do not need to debug the application to run it once it's productive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NameOfReportViewer.Refresh();
```

Should refresh the report Viewer for you, simply attach it to a method or event, what ever you wish.
Or simply do as Davide Piras said and hit the refresh button on the report!